# SSHFS messes up everything if i lose connection

Tags: 12.04, sshfs

This is becoming increasingly annoying and borderline despairing:

I use sshfs to mount directories from remote servers.
I work in a laptop with a docking station so I'm usually connected through ethernet. Many times I need to grab my laptop and go work in another location using the company's WIFI connection.
If i forget to "fusermount -u" all the different mounts, I need to restart the computer or at least logout login, which is very annoying and unproductive.

When i say everything is messe up i mean:

- My console stops working if i do something as simple as 'ls'
- I can't unmount either through the console or the File Browser
- Consequently, i can't mount it again, therefore i can't work

Does anyone relate to this problem? and know of a good solution?

Thank you

Comment: [This answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14143/what-is-a-better-way-to-deal-with-server-disconnects-of-sshfs-mounts) might be interesting.

Comment: i've tried it and it works!!! want to add it as an answer, so i can accept it as the right one? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## How to setup sshfs with the "reconnect" option

Pulled from this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14143/what-is-a-better-way-to-deal-with-server-disconnects-of-sshfs-mounts#41029).

You can run sshfs with the *"reconnect"* option. We use sshfs with PAM/automount to share server files for each workstation in our network. We use `-o reconnect` as parameter for sshfs, mostly because our users suspended their computers and on wake sshfs would not reconnect (or respond, or anything).

For example:

```
sshfs mvaldez@192.168.128.1:/home/mvaldez/REMOTE /home/mvaldez/RemoteDocs -o reconnect,idmap=user,password_stdin,dev,suid
```

Just a note, if the remote computer is really down, sshfs may become unresponsive for a long time.